# How can I ask for a quick shelter under someone's umbrella?

Tags: grammar, sentence

Scenario: suppose it is pouring outside and I need to get to my car by walking and I don't have an umbrella, but one of my coworker does. Can I casually ask if I could also walk under the umbrella? I hope this makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: "May I share your umbrella?"

Comment: If your car is not on the route to your colleague's car, you could ask "Would you mind walking me to my car? I don't have an umbrella."